# Ubuntu - not able to fix broken package

Tags: ubuntu, installation, skype, dpkg, apt

I'm trying to install Skype on Ubuntu 12, x64. but it is not working. When I try to fix the broken packages I'm getting the following errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  skype:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  skype:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 269 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 36.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype-bin:i386 (4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) breaks skype (<< 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) and is installed.
  Version of skype:i386 to be configured is 4.1.0.20-1.
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1
```

Please suggest what I should do to fix this issue.

Comment: This is off-topic here. You should move it to http://askubuntu.com

Comment: You should be asking this in [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get update` first?